# Difference between Connected Component labeling and Image Segmentation?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

Can someone explain the difference between Connected Component labeling and Image Segmentation in image processing? I've read about these techniques and found the outcome of both is almost same

Answer (score 3):

Segmentation is a problem statement: How do you assign a finite set of labels to each pixel in an image, ideally so that the labels correspond to real-world objects you're looking for?

Connected component labeling is (or can be seen as) one very simple approach to solving that problem: Simply assign the same unique label to connected sets of pixels that share some binary characteristic (e.g. brightness above some fixed threshold).

It is however by no means the only or the best approach: Just google for "[Graph cut segmentation](https://www.google.de/search?q=graph%20cut%20segmentation&tbm=isch)" or "[Watershed segmentation](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=isch&q=watershed%20segmentation)" to find examples that simply aren't possible with connected component labeling, like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connected components labeling scans an image and groups its pixels into components based on pixel connectivity. Connected components, in a 2D image, are clusters of pixels with the same value, which are connected to each other through either 4-pixel, or 8-pixel connectivity.
image segmentation can use any applicable algorithm to segment the voxels of interests which satisfy the feature that the user is looking for. This means not all the segmented voxels are connected together according to connected components. Sometimes, the VOI is obtained using C.C depending on what the VOI is. But most of the times in image processing for example if you are looking for a specific shape in your image, you can not use C.C since not all the voxels in the VOI are connected together.